# 50% Transparent background of Navigation Buttons, Segment buttons in iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, transparent, customization

Is there a way to customize navigation button, segment button background like iBooks?

Check out iBooks shelf top left corner. the button background is about 50% transparent. 
What a pretty!

Any one konw how to emplement it?

All Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as though it's a `UIButton` with an alpha of say, 0.5, ontop of a `UINavigationbar` with a custom background.

Try dropping something like this into your `appDelegate.m`

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigationBar.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

Alternatively you could drop in a method here,

And when you add your button to the Navigation bar..

```
button.alpha = 0.5;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I recommend using an image with 50% transparency, not setting the button.alpha. In the latter case, the label or foreground image is affected by the alpha as well.

Comment: Thanks for great comments. I think button.alpha will affect button's text transparency, that's not I want. 

Let me try transparent background image. 

Again. Thanks Bongeh and Ortwin.